# Block not displayed on translated views page

Tags: i18n-l10n, blocks

I'm having an issue where my menu block doesn't appear on certain pages in a different language.

I have my main navigation shown in a menu block and it appears on my news view at `mysite.com/consumers/news/year/2015` and articles at `/consumers/news/article-title`

The problems is there is content in other languages and the block does not appear on `/fr/consumers/news/year/2015` nor `/fr/consumers/news/test-fr-article`

The block is not restricted to any users, roles, languages or content types. The visibility filter is set to **Only the listed pages**

```
consumers*
fr/consumers*
```

but it just doesn't show up on those specific French pages for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the issue was there was a menu position rule for `consumers/news*` in any language appearing under a menu item in the English language menu. I set this rule to be English only then replicated it for French language items under the French menu